# Accessing individual array indexes when the array is in an objects variable

Tags: java, arrays, oop

So I have a data class whiplash which is created in a main program, inside this class is an instance variable of player which contains x amount of players and their variables

```
public class Whiplash {

private int rounds;
private WhiplashQuestions questions;
private Player[] players;

public Whiplash(int ROUNDS, WhiplashQuestions QUESTIONS, Player[] PLAYERS) {
    setRounds(ROUNDS);
    setPlayers(PLAYERS);
    setWhiplashQuestions(QUESTIONS);
}



public int getRounds() {
    return rounds;

}

public void setRounds(int rounds) {
    this.rounds = rounds;
}

public Player[] getPlayers(int id) {
    return players[id];
}

public void setPlayers(Player[] players) {
    this.players = players;
}

 public WhiplashQuestions getQuestions() {
    return questions;
}

public void setWhiplashQuestions(WhiplashQuestions question) {
    this.questions = question;
}
```

}

```
public class Player {


private int id;
private int points;
private String player;

   public Player(int ID, int POINTS, String PLAYER) {
    setId(ID);
    setPoints(POINTS);
    setPlayer(PLAYER);
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setPoints(int points) {
    this.points = points;
}

public String getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

public void setPlayer(String player) {
    this.player = player;
}
```

}

```
else if (command.startsWith("#whiplash")) {
        int usercount = getUserCount(client);
        String users[] = getUsersInRoom(client);
        Player[] player = new Player[usercount];

        player = convertUsersToPlayers(users, usercount);
        WhiplashQuestions q = new WhiplashQuestions("Whats your favorite color? ");

        Whiplash wl = new Whiplash(10, q, player);
        startWhiplash(wl);
public Player[] convertUsersToPlayers(String[] users, int userCount) {
    Player p[] = new Player[userCount];

    int u = users.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        p[i] = new Player(i, 0, users[i]);
    }

    return p;
}

public int getUserCount(ConnectionToClient client) {
    String room = client.getInfo("room").toString();
    int count = 0;

    Thread[] clientThreadList = getClientConnections();

    for (int i = 0; i < clientThreadList.length; i++) {

         ConnectionToClient clientProxy = ((ConnectionToClient) clientThreadList[i]);
        if (clientProxy.getInfo("room").equals(room)) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

public String[] getUsersInRoom(ConnectionToClient client) {
    String room = client.getInfo("room").toString();
    int connectedUsers = getUserCount(client);
    String[] usersInRoom = new String[connectedUsers];

    Thread[] clientThreadList = getClientConnections();

    for (int i = 0; i < clientThreadList.length; i++) {

        ConnectionToClient clientProxy = ((ConnectionToClient) clientThreadList[i]);

        if (clientProxy.getInfo("room").equals(room)) {
            try {
                //System.out.println(clientProxy.getInfo("userName".toString()));
                usersInRoom[i] = clientProxy.getInfo("userName".toString()).toString();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return usersInRoom;
}
```

So in my main program I create an instance of whiplash by converting strings of players to Player type, and then passing the proper values. I want to be able to access the individual Player[] indexes from the main program and am confused about the syntax to do so. For example in the main program if I want to get the 3rd players player string of an instance of whiplash to print can I do something along the lines of System.out.print(whiplash.getPlayers[3].getPlayers().toStrng()); ?

Comment: Where is your main program?

Comment: and [3] would actually be the fourth element. In Java arrays are 0 based...

Comment: Added the main program, and noted about the index.

Comment: Also I don't see where you have overridden the `toString()` method so it will probably output the `Object.toString()` nothing that tells you what player...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That is what I am wondering. Whiplash has an variable of Player which contains a String of player name. Can I call that player name from my main program or do I have to redesign my program?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: This won't even compile because your `getPlayers` method returns a `Player` object but the definitions says it is returning an Array...

Comment: `getPlayers` returns `Player[]`, so `whiplash.getPlayers()[3]` is the syntax

Answer (score 0):

So this is the syntax I was looking for and worked inside a loop (looping with i)

```
 wl.getPlayers()[i].getPlayer();
```